# Retrieve the session cookies in the proxy server (PHP)

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I am trying to set up a proxy server between my college's webkiosk and my client, so that I can authenticate on the behalf of my client and cache his data by crawling the college servers. I intend to develop an HTML5 app using this, so that I can provide these details to the client from the browser database implementations for his offline access. But the problem is in the login process. I am successfully able to send a post query to the server sending it the login form details. But, I cannot store the Session cookies the server returns, which leads to me not being able to continue with the authenticated session.

I researched the internet for 2 weeks, and I ak not able to find anything. Can anyone please guide me as to how should I go about this?

P. S. I am using PHP as my server side language.

Comment: If in your response header exists cookie it will be saved in browser automatically. You can use PHP method `setcookie` to add cookie to response header.

Comment: I don't want to save the cookie in the browser. I want to save it in the PHP server which will be intercepting the traffic between the browser and the college server.

Comment: Show us what you've already tried, it's not really clear what you're trying to do. Pseudocode with expected result would be enough

Comment: @Swanav Why save cookie in server, you must create session based on auth. cookie value.

Comment: My college provides a webkiosk, for students to check their marks, attemdance etc. Sadly, the UX sucks, and the kiosk is not an app for us to access our previous data without going online. So what I intend to build is an app, which communicates to my servers for the data. My server, in turn uses the user's credentials to access the webkiosk and cache the data in my server. I can easily take the user's credentials and send a post query to the webkiosk, just like their own login form. What I am unable to replicate is that their login page stores a session variable in the browser.

Comment: I can retrieve the HTML using file_get_contents() but not the headers.

Comment: @Swanav have you tried using curl?

Comment: I saw curl being used to set cookies. How do I get cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways with cURL:

1) A bit ugly, bit easier (for your needs, I think) to use

```
$url = '';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
$cookies = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
}
var_dump($cookies);
```

2) PHP's "intended" way:

```
$filepath = '';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $filepath);
```

Second way provides you with saved cookie in a file, which you can use to keep your session between curl calls. Meaning, you just pass this option to curl and unless you reset your session, you're going to be using one you saved.